# how to create a stacked bar chart with images in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stacked-chart

i am trying to create a stacked bar chart with images on each rectangle and it was creating images separately in the body, can someone please help me in it.
the output of my code is showing images in an another g class i need those images to be displayed in the respective rectangles.

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("rect")
.data(piedata)
.enter()
.append("svg:image")
.attr("xlink:href",function(d) {return d.data.image;})
.attr("width",50)
.attr("height",50)
```

js link : http://jsfiddle.net/sai20/5dzpc3wn/

Comment: Take this fiddle, add some non-local images so we can see what's going on and sort out the errors you get in the console first http://jsfiddle.net/cz37x2pk/

Comment: you can check it now and i need those image to take each rectangle and if the size of rectangle is less i want to make that image hide @RobSchmuecker

Comment: Check what?  Please post link

Comment: ooops sorry 
http://jsfiddle.net/sai20/cz37x2pk/2/

Comment: That doesn't work, it doesn't have d3 included and there are still local images.

Comment: can u please check this now 
hope it was giving out properly 
https://jsfiddle.net/sai20/cz37x2pk/4/

Comment: if that is not working u can check this 
http://jsfiddle.net/sai20/cz37x2pk/2/

Comment: @sai i would recommend that instead of two _data_ set piedata and data why not have one single dataset. I mean let the dataset _data_ also hold the image location also along with other metrics?

Comment: u actually no need the var values and var data
i combined both datasets and created third one var piedata
and i used only that in the code

Comment: @sai but piedata you are not using you are still using the data...is there a particular fiddle where done the change.

Comment: @cyril i am using both datasets , piedata is used to assign images and even though does that make any difference ?. because i need to append the images to rect but this was showing an error. it will be helpful to me if you can suggest me some changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose you have a single data set because you are creating rectangle with one dataset on one section, then with the other dataset you  making g group... in that group you are putting an image.

I would suggest have a single g per data in the dataset.
And in that g append your image and rectangle...life is easy.
Something like this

```
var mygroups = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(piedata)
    .enter().append("g");
mygroups
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(d.y1);
})
    .attr("height", function (d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
})
    .attr("class", "rectangle")
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.label);
});
mygroups
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href",function(d) {return d.image})
    .attr("height", function (d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
}).attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(d.y1);
});
```

Working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/0xo38x8q/7/

Comment: oh ya its working 
*i am creating g classes and calling two datasets so its not appending to that g class properly*
thanks alot :)

Comment: yes it is working and really thanks for that .
i actually have one more question can i actually hide images if their height is less than some value(which i can fix that height)??

Comment: To accept the answer you need to checkmark the post...
Yes! you can make display none for height something like this:
_.style("display", function (d) {
    if (size) {return "none"} else return "block";
});_